# How to add netconsole to kernel with OpenWRT

Tags: linux-kernel, console, openwrt

I'm using OpenWRT and I'm trying to work with netconsole instead of serial cable to debug kernel messages. By default, netconsole is not defined in OpenWRT, and I can't add it through menuconfig. There is no documentation for it anywhere. Any help to add netconsole to the kernel would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Sure, this shouldn't be complicated :) What does kernel's config say about CONFIG_NETCONSOLE?

Comment: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/admin-guide/serial-console.rst and http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt

Comment: thank you but I've already read this documentation. It explain how to use net console, but not how to add it to kernel...

Answer (score 1):

Run: make kernel_menuconfig and select the option.
But that alone won't help you. Netconsole requires kernel boot parameters to be set, most important, the destination address where the console messages are sent. You need to modify your bootloader to pass that parameter to the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this.
First you need to look at your *.config* file, which is found in the linux folder with the version you working with.
for example, I'm working with qca/src/linux-3.14.
This *.config* is being build in the compilation.
you can see the field

```
# CONFIG_NETCONSOLE is not set
```

The configurations in this file will define what will be built and what not.

So in order to build this module, go to your target folder, in linux/generic/ there is another configs files, mine is *config-3.14*. yours will be as your linux version you using.
change `CONFIG_NETCONSOLE is not set` to `CONFIG_NETCONSOLE=m`
and add `CONFIG_NETCONSOLE_DYNAMIC=y`'.
Now in compilation, the first *.config* file will be with the correct configuration and netconsole.ko module will be created.

This is valid for adding to kernel any module that affected by .config file.
Of course, you need to add this module manually, or add the module as part of kernel `CONFIG_NETCONSOLE=y` but I've had some problems with this.